# Existe alguma forma parecida com o método .format do python para o VBA no Excel?

Tags: java, python, vba, excel-vba

No python usando o .formato para isso:

> usuários = ['perfil1', 'perfil2']
>
> print("www.instagram.com/f{usuários[0]}/")

Logo sairia:
[www.instagram.com/perfil1/](http://www.instagram.com/perfil1/)

Existe algum método parecido no vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desconheço forma de passar a variável diretamente no corpo da string, o VBA não interpreta assim.
Você pode concatenar a string + variável + string com o operador **&**

```
Sub exemplo()

Dim usuários As Variant

usuários = Array("pedro", "paulo")

Debug.Print "www.instagram.com/" & usuários(0) & "/"

Debug.Print "www.instagram.com/" & usuários(1) & "/"

End Sub
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tudo bem com você?

Acredito que o que você procura seria algo como o código abaixo, ou seja, atribuir um valor a uma variável de texto e criar um link usando o valor dessa variável:

```
Sub Perfil()

Dim Usuario As String

Usuario = "perfil1"

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

'Cria o link
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="https://www.instagram.com/" & Usuario


End Sub
```

Nesse código, é criado um link do Instagram usando o usuário mencionado na célula selecionada pelo código (célula "A1").

Espero que ajude!